# What information is sent when a company requests my credit report?

Tags: credit-report

As I understand it, there are a few types of credit inquiries

- Hard pull (applying for new credit, loans, etc.)
- Soft pull ("account review" inquiries, FICO score services, etc.)

  - Promotional inquiry (companies looking to market to me)

For each of these inquiries:

- What information does the requesting party receive

  - Number of accounts
  - The names of the financial institutions
  - Credit limits
  - Balances
  - Payment history
  - Other inquiries
  - In aggregate or in the same detail I see when I review my own reports
- What requirements are there for issuing this type of inquiry

  - Written/oral authorization?
  - SSN
  - Name + address
- Any other interesting details about the inquiry or the information presented

Comment: You can request your own credit report (first request in a year from any of the three US agencies is free, and checking its accuracy is wise). That may not include the score number, but should have most or all of the other information.

Comment: @keshlam: I'm aware that I can obtain a credit report but that's not the question I'm asking.  I'm interested in knowing more about the other side of credit reports.  For example, a company issuing a promotional inquiry gets more limited information than one issuing a hard pull as part of an authorized credit application but exactly what information is covered, I'm not sure.

Comment: @keshlam, The credit report you get on yourself can include _more_ information that what a bank would get on you. For example, in the US, medical collections will be listed differently with less detail to a lender. http://www.experian.com/ask-experian/20080820-medical-collection-accounts-on-a-credit-report.html